# How i resolved Error: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms ,couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb, timeout, nodejs-server

How i resolved Error: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms ,couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB connection error: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162342/mongodb-connection-error-mongotimeouterror-server-selection-timed-out-after-30)

Comment: yes, It is the answer of my question, which i found during troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this error while connection MondoDB locally.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Using these following Steps Reconnect or again connect MongoDB locally.
 1. Open Two cmds in **bin** folder, where MongoDB is installed.
     like: (C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe)

2. In first cmd run: `mongod`, afterward command is run as per below picture.
   [image]
3. In second cmd run: `mongo`
   [image]

After doing all above steps reconnect the MongoDB locally

Comment: you can accept your answer, as it will help others to find solution